# Don't want to remove branch x after merge with branch y and master is it posible?

Tags: git, github, version-control

Example :

I have three branch x, y and master.

I am working on branch "x" after done I want to merge branch "x" with "y" and continue to work on branch "x" after fixing all bugs merge branch "x" with "y" as well as with "master" is it possible.

In other words I have 2 server I want to manage them with two separate branch.

Comment: Your branch only gets deleted if you delete it...

Comment: Yes but it is not showing in bitbucket branch . I want to merge with other branches also.

Comment: What are you asking?  Do you not know how to do a merge in Git?

Comment: So your question is actually "how do I merge branches in BitBucket without deleting the merged branch"

Comment: I want to merge single branch with multiple branch for two differ server. one of my server link with branch "x" and other is link with branch "master"

Comment: My question is it possible to merge branch x with branch y not with master branch and after fix all issues merge branch x with y as well as master for sync my code in both branches and then pull on server using command line for there related branches. hope you got my point.

Comment: Are you sure you know the basics of git, branch and merge ? If not may be have a look at these and ask the question then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 branches in your local repository. 
Firstly you want to push those branches to BitBucket so they are visible in BitBucket. You do that using the commands

```
git push -u origin master
git push -u origin x
git push -u origin y
```

Now you make changes on x and then want to merge that with y.

```
git checkout y
git merge x
```

Now push branch x and y to BitBucket as before.

After more changes you want to merge x to y and to master. Use the commands

```
git checkout y
git merge x
git checkout master
git merge x
```

Now push all Branches to BitBucket as before.

Notes:

1. BitBucket does not delete merged branches. Are you sure you are pushing the branches?
2. After the steps above all three branches will be the same. Are you sure that's what you want?
3. You might want to consider creating a branch per feature, rather than for each server. See https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows for popular Git workflows.
4. Assuming x and y represent pre-production servers and master represents the production server, you can easily just move the feature branches to the x and y servers, then merge to master when you're happy. When everything is correct all servers should match master.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use bitbucket, but if it automatically cleans up merged branches for you (and you checked that there is no option to disable this behaviour), then rest assured that this is bitbucket's doing, not git.

A merge works like this in `git`. Assume `a` and `b` are two commits, and `A` and `B` are two branches pointing to those commits respectively (a branch is nothing more than such a pointer, in `git`).

- Mix the contents of `a` and `b`.
- Create a new commit `c`, with parent-commits `a`, `b`.
- Change the pointer `A` to point at `c` (assuming you had `a`/`A` checked out during the merge and merged `b` "into" `a`).
- Check-out the contents of `c` into the working directory (a.k.a. `HEAD`).

`B` is not touched at all. `a` and `b` are not touched either (commits never change in any way in `git`, they absolutely cannot, except for eventually being removed by garbage collection if nothing points to them anymore).

So, either do your merge in your local `git` commandline and thus avoid whatever bitbucket did to your branch `B`. Or explicitely recreate the `B` branch to point at `b` again after the merge.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have forked the branch **x** from **y** to fix bugs that are already mentioned in your backlog, merging **x** into **y** via a **PR**(pull request) would generate the status **merged** of this PR, as well as it's **closed** status.

**Deleting** **x** branch is done manually in **github**, and that might not be the case for BitBucket, it seems that in your case the branch is deleted automatically once the **PR** is merged.

> This is BAD for your development experience? > The answer is NO.
>
> Why? > The concept of **version control repository** is that the PR of every bug fix should be elaborated from a new forked branch.
>
> Consider the case of multiple developers working on different bug fixes. So that the job needs to be done seamlessly, every bug should be treated in a separate PR;think about the code review discussion for each one. If all those subjects are treated in the same context(PR), it will be a real mess for your working velocity.

Answer (score 0):

It seems branch `x` and `y` are in a server (let's call it server1), and `master` branch is in another (server2). And it’s possible to merge `x` into `y` and `master` separately.

**Merge `x` into `y`:**

```
# In the local repo of server 1 (git clone <URL for server1>)
git checkout y 
git merge x
```

**Merge `x` into `master`:**

```
# In local repo of server2 (git clone <URL for server2>)
git remote add server1 <URL for server2> -f
git checkout master
git merge server1/x
```

Now changes on `x` branch in server1 is merged in server2 `master` branch.

**Note:** If there has merge conflict during merge, you need to modify and save the conflict files, and then use `git add .` and `git commit`.